# Could not set the selected property of a multi-column ListBox in Excel VBA UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns, userform, checkedlistbox

I am unable to check an item in a multi-column user-form ListBox. The line `lstPreConditionLogic.Selected(lstPreConditionLogic.ListCount) = True` generates the following error:

> Run-time error '380': Could not set the Selected property. Invalid property value

I tried setting the value to `-1` , `checked` but it did not work.

**VBA Code**

```
Private Function FillPreConditionLogicList()
    Dim varTemp             As Variant
    Dim intLoop             As Integer
    Dim strExpression       As String
    Dim PreConditionLogic   As clsPreConditionLogic

    With lstPreConditionLogic
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
        .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
        strExpression = TrimBlank(shtExpressionEditor.Range("rngExpText").Offset(, 1).Value)
        For intLoop = 0 To mDicPreConditionLogic.Count - 1
            Set PreConditionLogic = mDicPreConditionLogic.Items(intLoop)
            .AddItem
            .List(intLoop, 0) = PreConditionLogic.Name
            .List(intLoop, 1) = PreConditionLogic.StartEnclosure
            .List(intLoop, 2) = PreConditionLogic.EndEnclosure
            varTemp = GetEnclosedString(strExpression, PreConditionLogic.StartEnclosure, PreConditionLogic.EndEnclosure)
            If varTemp <> "" Then
                lstPreConditionLogic.Selected(lstPreConditionLogic.ListCount) = True '//Gives Error
                strExpression = varTemp
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must subtract `-1` from your `.ListCount` …

```
lstPreConditionLogic.Selected(lstPreConditionLogic.ListCount - 1) = True
```

Because the list index stats counting at `0` but eg if the `ListCount = 5` then the index of these 5 entries are `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` which means the last valid index is `.ListCount - 1`.